# Updating from internal network server (Windows)

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've written an extension which is hosted as unlisted in the Chrome web store.

It's deployed to around 150+ machines - but some of those are prohibited from being connected to the internet.  As a result, normally the extension is installed from the store, then their internet access is revoked - with internal network access only.

According to the Google documentation ([Alternative Extension Distribution](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions)), it's possible to update the registry with an update_url to update the extension from.

The part I'm confused about is they seem to imply that the only value you can set it to is https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx.

My hope was that I could set this value on the appropriate machines to a location internally that those machines can access, so that when I update the extension they can pull the update from those internal servers.

So my question is - why have Google bothered to provide this capability, when you can only set the update_url to the chrome store for Windows machines?  And if I'm wrong and you *can* set it to an internal server for updates - does anyone have experience of doing so and how do you debug any issues with the update?

In case anyone wonders - no, reactivating internet access to those devices is not an option.

Thanks in advance!

Tony

Comment: As for why: on Linux you can use any local URL there so evidently the restriction is caused by the enormous amount of malware abusing this feature in Windows/Mac.

Comment: Yeah I get that bit.  What I fail to understand is why the feature is there in Windows in the first place, if all you can do is point it to the Chrome store. As it's already installed via the official destination, I would have thought that after that point you could then point it to an internal destination for further updates.